# Modify Project Explorer in Eclipse RCP - Package/Project Presentation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP project I'm working on which uses the Project Explorer as default Navigator. For this Project Explorer I want to set the Project and also the Package Presentation hirarchical as the default value. Is there any Method or Extension Point so set these values for start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by settin the preferences for the providing plugins:

```
IEclipsePreferences workbenchPrefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.ui.workbench");
    workbench.putBoolean("org.eclipse.ui.commands/state/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.changeProjectPresentation/org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioState", true);

    IEclipsePreferences jdtPrefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.jdt.ui");
    jdtPrefs.putInt("org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.layout", 1);
```

With this set both, the package and the project presentation, changed to hirarchical on startup.